# adobe air gotoandstop don't work

Tags: flash, air, adobe

I have such a problem:

I have some movie clip with two different childs on it: "instruction" and "back_anim". They have the same structure, except one thing: "instruction" have classic tween, "back_anim" have "shape tween". I'm running it on Adobe Air 2.6 for Android. On each of this childs are two labels: "show", "hide". All stop frames present. And I have such a code to controll them:

```
protected function fadeOut(event:Event):void {
            line_mc.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,fadeOut);
            if (line_mc.hasOwnProperty('back_mask_anim')){
                line_final_anim_count++;
                (line_mc['back_mask_anim'] as MovieClip).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFinalAnimComplete);
                (line_mc['back_mask_anim'] as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay("show");//show
            }
            if (line_mc.hasOwnProperty('instruction')){
                line_final_anim_count++;
                (line_mc['instruction'] as MovieClip).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFinalAnimComplete);
                (line_mc['instruction'] as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay('hide');
            }
            if(line_final_anim_count == 0){ 
                setTimeout(lineComplete,time_before_fade_out);
            }
        }

        protected function checkFinalAnimComplete(event:Event):void {
            var anim_mc:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
            trace("anim_mc.frame " + anim_mc.currentFrame + " of " +anim_mc.totalFrames + 
            "name = " + anim_mc.name);
            if(anim_mc.currentFrame == anim_mc.totalFrames) {
                anim_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFinalAnimComplete);
                line_final_anim_count--;
            }
            trace("line_final_anim_count: " + line_final_anim_count);
            if(line_final_anim_count == 0){ 
                lineComplete();
            }
        }
```

but!!! "instruction" - plays well, "back_anim" - enters to endless cycle on stop frame.
When I do :  (line_mc['back_mask_anim'] as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(7);   next frame after stop frame - all ok. Whats the matter? Anyone face with such problem? Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue.
Maby someone it will help.

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?335765-gotoAndPlay%28%29-and-frame-script-stop%28%29

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this weird issue by creating an movieclip with all things from stage the gotoandstop function seems to work with movieclips but not with the stage directly.

Hope I helped!